Flutter - very time I export I have errors unless
Due to Googles request to change the minsdk target I updated my project. It also required me to update gradle. After several attempts it was giving me errors so instead I migrated the project to a clean Flutter installation, everything new.
I'm using gradle wrapper distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip
In settings.gradle I'm using:
 id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false

After I run flutter clean I run flutter build appbundle, and I always get the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
 > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

...so then I run
flutter pub outdated

...which tells me everything is all up-to-date. THEN I run flutter build appbundle again and it works!!
And sometimes, after Flutter clean I am told to run flutter pub outdated, but I immediately get the error:
ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED file system exception thrown while trying to create a symlink from source to dest

..Then I run the same thing again and it runs.
but as my dependencies are all up to date, why do I have to run flutter pub outdated to get rid of the error? And how are the two linked?
